# How to efficiently train a CNN model having large image dataset

Tags: machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I am beginner in machine learning. I am making a CNN model using keras to detect pest from leaf image. During training the data, memory exceed and I was unable to train. I have used kaggle/Google Collab but in both I have memory probelm.
I was suggested to use Data Generator, but while trying to do, I was unable to do. Is there any other way to efficiently train or any example whether data generator is used(Have seen many examples but have problem while adding.

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import cv2
from os import listdir
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers.core import Activation, Flatten, Dropout, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



EPOCHS = 25
INIT_LR = 1e-3
BS = 32
default_image_size = tuple((256, 256))
image_size = 0
directory_root = 'PlantVillage/'
width=256
height=256
depth=3

#Function to convert images to array

def convert_image_to_array(image_dir):
    try:
        image = cv2.imread(image_dir)
        if image is not None:
            image = cv2.resize(image,default_image_size)
            return img_to_array(image)
        else:
            return np.array([])
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error : {e}")
        return None


image_list, label_list = [], []
try:
    print("[INFO] Loading images ...")
    root_dir = listdir(directory_root)

    #Looping inside root_directory
    for directory in root_dir :
        # remove .DS_Store from list
        if directory == ".DS_Store" :
            root_dir.remove(directory)

    for plant_folder in root_dir :
        plant_disease_folder_list = listdir(f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}")
        print(f"[INFO] Processing {plant_folder} ...")

        #looping in images
        for disease_folder in plant_disease_folder_list :
            # remove .DS_Store from list
            if disease_folder == ".DS_Store" :
                plant_disease_folder_list.remove(plant_folder)

        #If all data taken not able to train
        for images in plant_disease_folder_list:
            image_directory = f"{directory_root}/{plant_folder}/{images}"
            if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".JPG") == True:
                image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
                label_list.append(plant_folder)



    print("[INFO] Image loading completed")  
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error : {e}")



#Get Size of Processed Image
image_size = len(image_list)

#Converting multi-class labels to binary labels(belong or doesnot belong in the class)

label_binarizer = LabelBinarizer()
image_labels = label_binarizer.fit_transform(label_list)

#Saving label binarizer instance using pickle
pickle.dump(label_binarizer,open('label_transform.pkl','wb'))
n_classes = len(label_binarizer.classes_)

print(label_binarizer.classes_)

#Normalizing image from [0,255] to [0,1]
np_image_list = np.array(image_list, dtype = np.float)/255.0

#Splitting data into training and test set 80:20
print('Splitting data to train,test')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np_image_list, image_labels, test_size=0.2, random_state = 42)

#Creating image generator object which performs random rotations, shifs,flips,crops,sheers
aug = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range = 25, width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1, shear_range=0.2,
        zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip = True,
        fill_mode="nearest")

model = Sequential()

inputShape = (height, width, depth)
chanDim = -1
if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    inputShape = (depth, height, width)
    chanDim = 1

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding="same",input_shape=inputShape))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(32))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(n_classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))

#model.summary()
#Compiling the CNN
opt = Adam(lr= INIT_LR, decay= INIT_LR/EPOCHS)

#distribution
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer = opt, metrics=["accuracy"])

#training the Model
print("Training Model.....")

history = model.fit_generator(
        aug.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size= BS),
        validation_data = (x_test, y_test),
        steps_per_epoch = len(x_train) // BS,
        epochs = EPOCHS, verbose = 1
        )
```

*You find code in this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/emmarex/plant-disease-detection-using-keras) too.*

Comment: How many images are you training on? For training on 1-2M images, I used chunks of 10k images. So reading the 10k images into memory, fit the model, load the next chunk, fit the model, until all images have passed through an epoch, and then iterate for the amount of epochs desired. I don't know if Generators do something more clever however or if it affects accuracy.

Comment: def sgd(X_train, y_train, minibatch_size = 200):
    while True:
        for iter in range(n_iter):
            print('Iteration {}'.format(iter))

            # Randomize data point
            X_train, y_train = shuffle(X_train, y_train)
            for i in range(0, X_train.shape[0], minibatch_size):
                # Get pair of (X, y) of the current minibatch/chunk
                X_train_mini = X_train[i:i + minibatch_size]
                y_train_mini = y_train[i:i + minibatch_size]

        return X_train_mini,y_train_mini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you have loaded the complete data in the workspace, which fills lots of memory and create lots of extra load on the processes.

One thing you can used is `data-generator` with `flow_from_directory`, which allows you to define the `augmentation` and `pre-processing` pipeline along with `data on the fly`. The advantage here is that workspace doesn't have extra load of data. You can find an example [here](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/).

Feel free to ask question.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert images into binary format which is understandable by tensorflow called "tfrecord" format.

Please refer to the below links

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html